# Select once from duplicate XML info, display rest, and sort on a field

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting, foreach

I have an XML doc that looks like this.

```
<Results>
  <Name>Lab Asst1 </Name>
  <Subject> Math </Subject>
  <Marks>96</Marks>
  <Grade>A</Grade>

  <Name>Student1</Name>
  <Subject>Math</Subject>
  <Marks>90</Marks>
  <Grade>A</Grade>

  <Name>Student1</Name>
  <Subject>English</Subject>
  <Marks>70</Marks>
  <Grade>B</Grade>

  <Name>Lab Asst1 </Name>
  <Subject> Science</Subject>
  <Marks>99</Marks>
  <Grade>A</Grade>

    <Name>Student2</Name>
    <Subject>Science</Subject>
    <Marks>70</Marks>
    <Grade>B</Grade>

  </Results>
```

Using XSL, what is the simplest way to display, without showing the `<Name>` element twice? I would like to display the Lab Asst1 results first, assuming there is a text box that uses this value (comes in from C# code): 
Basically, something that does this part first:

```
    User: <Name>
    Your results are:
    <table> 
   <tr>
     <td> Subject </td>
     <td> Marks </td> 
     <td> Grade </td>
   </tr>
```

then call another template etc. or do a for-each or something....

```
<tr>
     <td> <xsl:value-of select="Subject"/>  </td>
     <td> <xsl:value-of select="Marks"/>  </td> 
     <td>  <xsl:value-of select="Grade"/> </td>
   </tr>
```

Such that my results appear like this:

```
User: Lab Asst1
        Your results are:
        Subject | Marks | Grade 
    -------------------------------------
         Science|  99   |   A
           Math |  96   |   A


        User:Student1
        Your results are:
        Subject | Marks | Grade 
    -----------------------------
           Math |  95   |   A
        English |  70   |   B

        User:Student2
        Your results are:
        Subject | Marks | Grade 
    -----------------------------
           Math |  70   |   B
```

Comment: Do you have control over the XML? It would be easier to work with if each set of data would be enclosed in a `Result` element of its own.

Comment: ok I just did that. each element, looks something like this now:  <Results><Result><Name/>
  <Subject/> <Marks/>
  <Grade/></Result></Results>

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and efficient solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kPersByName" match="Name" use="."/>
 <xsl:key name="kData" match="*"
          use="preceding-sibling::Name[1]"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:for-each select=
   "Name[generate-id()
        =
         generate-id(key('kPersByName', .)[1])
        ]
   ">
   <xsl:variable name="vData" select="key('kData', .)"/>

    User: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    Your results are:
    <table border="1">
       <tr>
         <td> Subject </td>
         <td> Marks </td>
         <td> Grade </td>
       </tr>

       <xsl:for-each select="$vData[self::Subject]">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Marks[1]"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Grade[1]"/></td>
        </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<Results>
  <Name>Lab Asst1 </Name>
  <Subject> Math </Subject>
  <Marks>96</Marks>
  <Grade>A</Grade>

  <Name>Student1</Name>
  <Subject>Math</Subject>
  <Marks>90</Marks>
  <Grade>A</Grade>

  <Name>Student1</Name>
  <Subject>English</Subject>
  <Marks>70</Marks>
  <Grade>B</Grade>

  <Name>Lab Asst1 </Name>
  <Subject> Science</Subject>
  <Marks>99</Marks>
  <Grade>A</Grade>

  <Name>Student2</Name>
  <Subject>Science</Subject>
  <Marks>70</Marks>
  <Grade>B</Grade>
</Results>
```

**produces the wanted, correct results**:

```
    User: Lab Asst1 
    Your results are:
    <table border="1">  <tr>
        <td> Subject </td>
        <td> Marks </td>
        <td> Grade </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Math </td>
        <td>96</td>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Science</td>
        <td>99</td>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
</table>

    User: Student1
    Your results are:
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td> Subject </td>
        <td> Marks </td>
        <td> Grade </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Math</td>
        <td>90</td>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>70</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
</table>

    User: Student2
    Your results are:
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td> Subject </td>
        <td> Marks </td>
        <td> Grade </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Science</td>
        <td>70</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Do note**:

1. **The [Muenchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml) is used**.
2. **In XSLT 2.0 it is easier and more convenient to use the [`<xsl:for-each-group>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#xsl-for-each-group)** instruction.

Comment: thank you so much!!!! I tried using XSLT 2.0 and <xsl:for-each-group> as per your suggestion to make it slightly simple, but it appears I cannot use neither <xsl:for-each-group> nor <xsl:key />  in XSLT 2.0 element with asp.net, though I have mentioned <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  > ! There's a compile error: System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: 'group-by' is not a recognized extension element.

Comment: @Amy: Microsoft hasn't an XSLT 2.0 processor. In .NET one could use Saxon.NET if one controls the server environment and is allowed to install it. Also, there is XQSharp (still in beta).

Comment: @Amy: My solution is an XSLT 1.0 solution and works with .NET's XSLT processors. Why just don't use it?

Comment: @Amy: `<xsl:node>` ??? There isn't any such xslt element and certainly there isn't such in my answer. Can't you simply run the transformation using your provided XML document? What is the problem?

Comment: sorry I just mis-typed it, I deleted my comment now but looks like you saw it. will keep you updated. no issues so far! thanks for your help.