# How to get a unique value from an XSL transformation?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I have the following XML file:

```
<document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="cars.xsd">
<manufacture id="1">
    <make>Audi</make>
    <classification>
        <list mid="1">
            <type>Sports</type>
        </list>     
        <list  mid="2">
            <type>Compact</type>
        </list>     
        <list  mid="3">
            <type>Compact</type>
        </list> 
    </classification>
</manufacture>
<manufacture id="2">
    <make>bmw</make>
    <classification>
        <list mid="1">
            <type>Sports</type>
        </list>     
        <list  mid="2">
            <type>Luxury</type>
        </list> 
        <list  mid="3">
            <type>Luxury</type>
        </list>                 
    </classification>
</manufacture>
</document>
```

Here is my current XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output doctype-public="-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" 
            doctype-system="http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd"
 method="xml" version="1.0" 
            omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
            indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" media-type="text/html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name="html">
<xsl:element name="head">           
    <xsl:element name="title">Automotives</xsl:element>
</xsl:element>

<xsl:element name="body">                    
<xsl:element name="ul">
<xsl:attribute name="class">pageitem</xsl:attribute>                    
    <xsl:for-each select="document/manufacture/classification/list">        
        <xsl:element name="li">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">menu</xsl:attribute>        
            <xsl:element name="p">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">name</xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:element name="a">                                
                    <xsl:value-of select="type"/>
                    <xsl:element name="br"/>    
                </xsl:element>      
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>                    
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>      
</xsl:element>  
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I get the following output without repeating the types?

```
Sports
Compact 
Luxury
```

I'm new to XSLT and I've tried using generate-id() as in: [Select once from duplicate XML info, display rest, and sort on a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167486/select-once-from-duplicate-xml-info-display-rest-and-sort-on-a-field)

But It didn't work for me as I couldn't understand the generate-id() code.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is *distinct* values, rather than *unique* ones. As Tim C said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention about generate-id, so that means you might have been reading about [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) here, and this is indeed what you need to get the distinct values. As you are interested in **type** elements, you start off my defining a key to easily look up such elements by their value.

```
<xsl:key name="types" match="type" use="." />
```

Now, to get distinct elements you iterate over all **type** elements, but you only output the distinct elements. And to tell they are distinct you check if they occur first in the key for their given value.

Here is the expression...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//type[generate-id() = generate-id(key('types', .)[1])]" />
```

But to break it down to its compenent parts...

`key('types', .)` - Returns all **type** elements for the current value

`key('types', .)[1]` - Returns the first element in the key

`generate-id(key('types', .)[1])` - Returns the unique identifier for that element

`generate-id() = generate-id(key('types', .)[1])` - Check whether the unique identifier for the current element equals the unique identifier for the first element in the key.

Thus, if they match, it is the first occurence, and can be output.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text" />
   <xsl:key name="types" match="type" use="." />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//type[generate-id() = generate-id(key('types', .)[1])]" />
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="type">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#10;')" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to you XML, the following is output

```
Sports
Compact
Luxury
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was a very detailed explanation and easy to understand.